# Databound textbox only updates after I edit it. Using MVVM in wpf form

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My textbox is data bound to the selecteditem property of a Datagrid. So as user selects different row of the datagrid the textbox gets updated with the selected row's value. The data binding connections are set up correctly (almost). Reason I say is this. TextBox value is not updated until and unless it click on it and then hit any key.
Here is a step by step what happens:
1. Say initial value of textbox is 1.
2. User clicks a row that has a column X value of 5.
3. I have to now click the textbox and type any key. Soon as I do that the selected row value appears.
4. Expected outcome should be no delay in user selecting a row and textbox's value updating.

So in essence the update of the textbox happens only after I click on it and make an edit. I have tried playing around with different UpdatetoSource property but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.
Also note this is my first ever question on StackOverflow so please forgive me if I am not following certain norms of asking questions (feedback welcome)

```
Model Class:
    class Account
      {
       public String AccountNumber{get;set;}
       public String CSSMeteterNumber{get;set;}
       public String CSSSDPNumber { get; set; }
      }

    ViewModel:
class AccountViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public AccountViewModel()
        {
            Load(); 
        }

        private Account _account;
        public Account Account
        {
            get
            {
                return _account;
            }
            set
            {
                _account = value;
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(_account));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
       public void Load()
        {
            Account a = new Account { AccountNumber = "200", CSSMeteterNumber = "100", CSSSDPNumber = "100" };
            Account = a;
            ObservableCollection<Account> accounts = new ObservableCollection<Account>();
            for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
            {
                accounts.Add(new Account { AccountNumber = "200", CSSMeteterNumber = "100", CSSSDPNumber = "100" });
            }
            AccountCollection = accounts;
        }

public partial class AccountView : Window
    {
        public AccountView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AccountViewModel aVM = new AccountViewModel();
            DataContext = aVM;
            CSS_E_DG.ItemsSource = aVM.AccountCollection.ToList();
        }
    }

AccountView Xaml
<Window x:Class="PlsWork.View.AccountView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlsWork.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AccountView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Account.AccountNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" Height="40" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>

        <DataGrid x:Name="CSS_E_DG" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="300" Height="300"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Account}" >

        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Where is `AccountCollection` defined, your `Datagrid` isn't bound, `OnPropertyChange(nameof(_account));` should be `OnPropertyChange(nameof(Account));`, there's a lot missing here to help IMHO...

Comment: `CSS_E_DG.ItemsSource = aVM.AccountCollection.ToList();` also if you want to follow `mvvm` you shouldn't be doing that... *dont' reference ui elements in code*... You need to have a collection defined in the viewmodel and then bind that to the view element...

Comment: `private ObservableCollection<Account> _accountCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<Account> AccountCollection { get; set; }`
It is defined right under Account

Comment: Can you please update your OP to include this code (above) where it needs to go and not as a comment. Otherwise this may get confusing to others.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ you have answered the question:
OnPropertyChange(nameof(Account)); is the fix. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Great, I am glad my comment proved to be useful, thanks and you are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnPropertyChange("Account")`

or

`OnPropertyChange("")`

In this case, you will update all the properties

Answer (score 2):

`OnPropertyChange(nameof(Account));` is the fix. Credit to @Çöđěxěŕ (see comments under post).
Before I had `OnPropertyChange(nameof(_account));` using the backing field as event arg.